# Job Scheduling in Java

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

I want to  run a Java program on a specific date.
I am developing a J2EE application that allows you to schedule Selenium test launch (JUnit) on a specified date..

Are there any solutions to do this? can you point me to technology that can help me to do this? 
any help is appreciated:) 
thanks for your help

Comment: Is it within a larger server process or standalone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing enough details, I would recommend using [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/). You can see an example of using it [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/examples/Example1.html).

Answer (score 3):

You provided very little information. You can schedule launch in scheduler of your operating system (like cron in Linux), or you can run a task from within your Java process, if the process is constantly running. For this see [Quartz Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/).

Comment: I apologize for the amount of information that I provided, I want to be as brief as possible ... in fact I am developing a J2EE application that allows you to schedule Selenium test launch (JUnit) on a specified date.. thank you to all those who try to help me

Comment: Then you should look for scheduling or timer services of your JEE container, or use Quartz on your own.

Comment: Apparently  Quartz gives great opportunity,I will consider this solution
thank you again for your help

Answer (score 0):

You could use crond or Windows Task Manager.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Java process running from now to the time it needs to start, look at Quartz.

If you need to have a Java process started from nothing, you must ask your operating system to invoke it for you.  For Linux check the "at" command.

Answer (score 0):

Cron on Unix, and Cron for NT on WindowsNT platforms (XP-Windows 7, Windows Server 4.0+).

Why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create and package modular java server-side tasks (that you can then schedule in any particular java scheduler of your choice) check out the [open source project called soafaces](https://code.google.com/p/soafaces/). Let's you create modular java Tasklets and also give them web based GUI customizer (customizer part is optional and based on google gwt).

Comment: Please consider adding some code here, that shows how the solution might look like.

Comment: Check example code on the soafaces wiki: https://code.google.com/p/soafaces/wiki/HowToCreateTasklet

Comment: The problem with links is, that they often get outdated after a while. That is the only reason why I'm asking for a little example.

Answer (score 0):

Scheduling can be implemented in many ways, it is also bit IO intensive, so if needed u might want to use non-java solutions

However you want to have java solutions may be below links should help you

**Spring Way** : https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/ and https://dzone.com/articles/schedulers-in-java-and-spring

**Non Spring solution**: https://github.com/knowm/Sundial